# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException when reloading table

Tags: java

I have a `changeTableView` method in my application. The method reloads a `TableView` with a new set of contents. Its object is to handle pagination. It will reset a table and load it with the rows for another page.

```
public void changeTableView(int index, int limit) {
    System.out.println("index: " + index + ", limit: " + limit);
    int newIndex = index * limit;

    List<Product> productSubList = allProducts.subList(Math.min(newIndex, allProducts.size()), Math.min(allProducts.size(), newIndex + limit));

    productListTable.getItems().clear();
    productListTable.setItems(null);

    ObservableList<Product> products = FXCollections.observableList(productSubList);
    productListTable.setItems(products);
}
```

The method is called for the first time at initialization with `index = 0` and subsequently by the following method.

```
    pagination.currentPageIndexProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
            changeTableView(newValue.intValue(), limit.get());
            System.out.println("new value: " + newValue.intValue() + ", limit: " + limit.get());
        }
    });
```

`changed` method gets called when the user asks for a different page.

However, changing pages throws the following exception.

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:1169)
    at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.size(ArrayList.java:998)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.size(ObservableListWrapper.java:335)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableViewSkin.getItemCount(TableViewSkin.java:325)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableViewSkin.updatePlaceholderRegionVisibility(TableViewSkin.java:561)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableViewSkin.updateRowCount(TableViewSkin.java:623)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableViewSkin.layoutChildren(TableViewSkin.java:426)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1018)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1028)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1028)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.layoutDirtyRoots(Scene.java:524)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.doLayoutPass(Scene.java:495)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.access$3900(Scene.java:173)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2205)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit$5.run(Toolkit.java:363)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit$5.run(Toolkit.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:361)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:384)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:463)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit$9.run(QuantumToolkit.java:332)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:76)
```

The culprit, I suspect here, is `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:1169)`

How can I stop this from happening without affecting my application's performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the documentation, `sublist()` returns a `view` of the `List`. Since it is a `view` it is not safe to keep it around and iterate multiple time.

[List.sublist()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList(int,%20int))

Instead you should make a copy of the sublist before passing around.

[Collections.copy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#copy(java.util.List,%20java.util.List))